# Django Attribute Error when using serializer

Tags: python, django

I would like to fetch the entire table. My model and serializer seems to be correct but I am getting the below error

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `symbol` on serializer `CompanySerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'symbol'.

Below is my Model

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Companies(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    isin = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Companies

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['symbol', 'name', 'isin',]
        # fields = '__all__'
        model = Companies
```

Below is my view
**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Companies
from .serializers import CompanySerializer
from django.core.serializers import json


class companiesView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):

        companies = Companies.objects.filter(id=1)
        serializer = CompanySerializer(companies)

        # json_serializer = json.Serializer()
        # json_serialized = json_serializer.serialize(companies)

        response = Response()
        response.data = {
            'named' : serializer.data,
        }

        return response
```

I am not sure what is causing this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

`companies` is a queryset, so what you have is a list of companies. If you want your serializer to work with a list of objects, just add `many=True`:

```py
        companies = Companies.objects.filter(id=1)
        serializer = CompanySerializer(companies, many=True)
        #                                         ^^^ Add this
```

Another way is to just get the company with id 1 using `get` instead of `filter`. In this case you don't have to add `many=True` since the serializer is working on a single object:

```py
        companies = Companies.objects.get(id=1)
        #                             ^^^ Use get instead of filter
        serializer = CompanySerializer(companies)
```